# Is it possible to make batch requests on different sites? And what about the same site but different subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, batch

I'm trying to get itens from different subsites but in the same site (it would be nice to know the method to different sites too, if possible) and when I try to do the same way when I do in same site it just doesnt work returning: (400) Invalid request.

Is it possible?

The way I do is:

`POST https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/_api/$batch`

`{"Content-Type":"multipart/mixed; boundary=c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720; charset=utf-8","Expect":"100-continue","Host":"https://contoso.sharepoint.com"}`

```
--c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/_api/web/lists/anyList1List/items HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

--c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/_api/web/lists/anyList2List/items HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata
```

The output:

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_fc6eee30-36b4-4303-88af-a8498561bbea",
  "$content": "base64encodebody...==",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/http",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/http; msgtype=response",
        "$content": "base64encodebody...==",
        "$applicationHttp": {
          "headers": {},
          "body": {
            "value": [
              {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": "Item #1",
                "...": "others properties hidden for readable content..."
              },
              {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Item #2",
                "...": "others properties hidden for readable content..."
              },
            ]
          },
          "statusCode": 200
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/http",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/http; msgtype=response",
        "$content": "base64encodebody...==",
        "$applicationHttp": {
          "headers": {},
          "body": {
            "value": [
              {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": "Item #1",
                "...": "others properties hidden for readable content..."
              },
              {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Item #2",
                "...": "others properties hidden for readable content..."
              },
            ]
          },
          "statusCode": 200
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I do:

`POST https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/_api/$batch`

`{"Content-Type":"multipart/mixed; boundary=c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720; charset=utf-8","Expect":"100-continue","Host":"https://contoso.sharepoint.com"}`

```
--c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/SubSite1/_api/web/lists/anySubSiteList1List/items HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

--c1e13017-60ac-406f-8268-cdbc586af720
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/masterSite/SubSite2/_api/web/lists/anySubSiteList2List/items HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata
```

The output ("Solicitação inválida" = "Invalid request"):

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_307c09a8-1bfc-4ccb-a60a-d6aa31e6a863",
  "$content": "base64==",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/http",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/http; msgtype=response",
        "$content": "base64=",
        "$applicationHttp": {
          "headers": {},
          "body": {
            "error": {
              "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
              "message": {
                "lang": "pt-BR",
                "value": "Solicitação inválida."
              }
            }
          },
          "statusCode": 400
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/http",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/http; msgtype=response",
        "$content": "base64=",
        "$applicationHttp": {
          "headers": {},
          "body": {
            "error": {
              "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
              "message": {
                "lang": "pt-BR",
                "value": "Solicitação inválida."
              }
            }
          },
          "statusCode": 400
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can't find it in official docs for SP REST API or OData protocol, but in according to the [PnP JS docs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/batching/), it is not. It seems search is the only way to do it in single request.